# Loosing data while joining tables in PHP

Tags: php, sql

I have joined two tables `images` and `post`. My script is working  as long as I have an empty row in `post`, and stops working when I remove it. Please help.

Post table:

```
id title
1  post
2  post2
```

Images table:

```
id img      post_id
1  fgh.jpg  2
2  fhhj.jpg 2
```

Here is my SQL:

```
    if ($stmt = $con->prepare("  SELECT p.*,i.img,title,id 
from post AS p JOIN images AS i ON i.post_id= p.id ")) {
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to select a row from table 'Post' whose corresponding row does not exist in table 'Images' then use LEFT JOIN like so:

```
if ($stmt = $con->prepare("  SELECT p.*,i.img,title,id 
from post AS p LEFT JOIN images AS i ON i.post_id= p.id ")) {
```